# Class-based enums in Vala?

Tags: vala

I'm wondering how to create class-based enums in Vala.

In Java you can do the following:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Action action = Action.COMPRESS;
        System.out.printf("Action name: %s, index %d", action.getName(), action.getIndex());
    }
}

class Action {

    public static final Action COMPRESS = new Action("Compress", 60);
    public static final Action DECOMPRESS = new Action("Decompress", 70);

    private String name;
    private int index;

    private Action(String name, int index) {
        this.name = name;
        this.index = index;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }
}
```

But when I try the following in Vala, `COMPRESS` and `DECOMPRESS` are always **null when accessing** from outside the `Action` class.

```
public static int main(string[] args) {
    stderr.printf("Action name: %s\n", UC.Action.COMPRESS.get_name());
}

public class UC.Action : GLib.Object {

    public static UC.Action COMPRESS   = new UC.Action("Compress");
    public static UC.Action DECOMPRESS = new UC.Action("Decompress");

    private string name;

    [CCode (construct_function = null)]
    private Action(string name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string get_name() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

That code outputs the following: `Performing (null)`.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: Your Vala members are not `static` like the Java ones are. Thus they only exist if an instance does.

Comment: @underscore_d I forgot, thanks for noticing. The problem is that they're still null if accessed from the main method.

Comment: I wonder if maybe Vala never bothers to construct `static` members if no instance is ever constructed. Try constructing a dummy instance in `main()` and see if anything changes?

Comment: That works! The static members are getting constructed properly if I create a dummy instance. Any idea what goes wrong in the vala compiler?

Comment: I don't know. You would need to consult the detailed documentation of Vala to determine whether what you want to do is even _intended_ to work. Then, if it _is_, but that's not happening, file a bug on the GNOME GitLab instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vala, static class members are initialized during the `class_init` GObject function, so they're not available until that has been called.

The easiest work-around is to just create an instance; you can throw it away immediately since all you're after is the side-effects.

Comment: Or ensure the type `typeof(UC.Action).ensure ();`, which should init the class